# Why the Name 'assert' in JUnit OR Android Test Cases?

Tags: junit, android-espresso, android-testing

I am trying to get my hands dirty with testing in **Android**. 
Came with many terms like `assertEquals`, `ViewAssertion`, `assertThat` etc from many testing frameworks.

But, always wondered why this name **assert** ? 
Searched on internet, but nothing got into my head.

Hope, somebody explain me in simple English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Merriam-Webste](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assert)r online dictionary:

> Definition of assert 
>   to state or declare positively and often forcefully or aggressively

So, when you call something like `assertEquals(input1, input2)`, you are simply stating that the two inputs are logically equal.

Comment: Thanks Tim for the answer. But, why not a simple word as Verify  ? I don't know, but assert feels heavy for me. It doesn't go into my head.

Comment: @akashPatra Assert was already the name of a directive in certain assembly languages.  This still doesn't explain why those earlier languages chose the term, but it might partially explain why the OO languages also use it.